# react js request result

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I have a problem getting a value and setting in my state in react
I can see data in console of my api response and everything goes well.

```
export default class index extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
            this.state={ products: [], filteredProducts:[]}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
         api.get('/products').then( result => this.setState({
            products: result.data.listProducts,
            filteredProducts: result.data.listProducts
        }))
        console.log(this.state.products)
    }
```

but when I console my state value, it appears an empty array

```
index.js:16 [] console.log(this.state
index.js:11 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] console.log( data request
```

Well I don't know if it's a problem with my back end

I made a map to filter what I will return to my front end since I have
an array of 3 objects
I don't know if I made the best option or if I can do better, if I can improve the code I would be happy if someone could alert me:

```
  async getAllProduct(req,res){
        try {
            const results = await Products.findAll({
                // raw: true, <= remove
                attributes:['id','name', 'float', 'price'],
                include: [{
                    model: SubCategory,
                    as: 'subcategory',
                    attributes: ['id','name'],
                },
                {
                    model:Exteriors,
                    as: 'exteriors',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
                {
                    model:Types,
                    as: 'types',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
            ],
            })
            const listProducts = []
            results.map(record =>
                record.get({ plain: true }));

            results.map( (products) => {
                const model = {
                    id: products.id,
                    name: products.name,
                    float: products.float,
                    price: products.price,
                    id_sub: products.subcategory.id,
                    subcategory: products.subcategory.name,
                    id_types: products.types.id,
                    type: products.types.name,
                    id_ext: products.exteriors.id,
                    exterior: products.exteriors.name,
                }
                listProducts.push(model);
            })
            if(listProducts){return res.status(200).json({listProducts})}
            else{return res.status(400).json({result: 'failed to get Products'})}
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async, you can't see updated state right after setting the state,

You can have callback in setState to check the updated state,

```
this.setState({
    products: result.data.listProducts,
    filteredProducts: result.data.listProducts
}, () => console.log(this.state.products)) //callback method
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `console.log` right after a state update you will log the old state. Try logging the state in `componentDidUpdate` to see if the state is actually empty:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log(this.state)
}
```

Comment: omg
thank you friend, could you just ask me one more question?

in my back end I already send my result using .json

so I don't have to do this on the front end

but something that got me worried i can't use my result.ok (appears as undefinied)

Comment: And one more question if you allow me I'm having to go a giant way to get to my data there is a way to decrease:
result.data.listProducts

Comment: @oemera, It should be `componentDidUpdate` and not `ComponentDidUpdate`. Another thing we don't compulsorily need `componentDidUpdate` to check updated state, we can have callback in setState.

Comment: @ravibagul91I fixed it, thanks for the hint. You are right in this case the callback would have been enough, but I thought showing him the lifecycle hook would be more benefical for him in other use cases.

Comment: @Gabriel You should create a new post with a more detailed explanation :)